# How do I add two sum queries together?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following two pseudo queries:

```
SELECT Sum(a)
FROM b
WHERE c
```

and

```
SELECT Sum(d)
FROM b
WHERE e
```

I want to sum these queries together to one value but I can't figure out the syntax. Note the `FROM` statement is the same ("b"). I've tried a `UNION` query but this gives me two values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iif()` inside `sum()` where you apply the conditions:

```
select sum(iif(c, a, 0)) + sum(iif(e, d, 0))
from b
```

Comment: Tried to go for this solution but I'm getting a 'cannot have aggregate function' error. Actual SQL is too long to post - should I open up a new question?

Comment: This code is valid in MS Access. I don't know how you use it. `c` and `e` are the conditions you apply for each sum and `a` and `e` are the columns that you want to sum.

Comment: @Jossy If your actual code changes the requirement and does not correspond to this question then post it in a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Since both queries will always return a single record, you could alternatively [cross join](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6#bmcross) the two subqueries and simply add the results, e.g.:

```
select r1 + r2 from
(select sum(a) as r1 from b where c) t1,
(select sum(d) as r2 from b where e) t2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT SUM(col1) 
FROM
(
SELECT Sum(a) col1
FROM b
WHERE c

UNION

SELECT Sum(d) col1
FROM b
WHERE e)  t
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following

Select sum(sumVal)

FROM

(SELECT Sum(a) sumVal
FROM b
where c

UNION

SELECT Sum(d) sumVal
FROM e
where f
)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this :

```
;WITH 
t1 as ( select sum(a) as a from b where c>20)
,
t2 as (select sum(d) as d from b where e is not null)
select t1.b1+t2.c2 as s from t1 inner join t2 on t1.b1 != t2.c2
```

Comment: Since when does MS Access support CTEs?